# How to sum using stream() by a certain type of variable

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to sum all the points from the same team and return a list of strings (team : totalPoints)

```
public class Player {
    String name;
    int team;
    int points;
}

List <Player> player= new ArrayList<>();
player.add(new Player("Michael",1,10)); 
player.add(new Player("Mike",2,15));
player.add(new Player("Tom",1,7));  
player.add(new Player("Marty",2,9));
```

I wanted to receive a `List<String`>, with: `"1 : 17" , "2 : 24"`

Comment: This is Java, so keywords are lowercase: `public`, `int`

Answer (score 3):

You could use, `Collectors.groupingBy` with a downstream `Collectors.summingInt` as :

```
List<String> result = player.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Player::getTeam,
                Collectors.summingInt(Player::getPoints)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> e.getKey() + " : " + e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I was looking forever for a method like `Collectors.summingInt()`. Very nice

Comment: @GBlodgett You could always use `Collectors.reducing(0, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: @GBlodgett `toMap(Player::getTeam, Player::getPoints, Integer::sum)` would work too.